# In Vue3, how to type a props in a Child component from a ref

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm in Vue3, using Composition API and setup pattern.
I have a parent component with a ref about an Array of object Book and I have a child component displaying a  with the books as options.

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <CustomSelect v-bind:bookOptions="bookList" />
  ...
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
interface Book {
  title: string
  description: string
}
let bookList= ref<Book[]>([]);
</script>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
  <select v-model="selectedBook" @click="print">
    <option value=null>----</option>
    <option v-for="book in props.bookOptions" :key="book.title" :value="book">
      {{ book.title }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{bookOptions?: Book[]}>();
const selectedBook= ref<Book| null>(null);

function print() {
  console.log(selectedBook.value)
}
</script>
```

I tried to type the bookOptions in the props but, in my parent component I have this error: *Argument of type '...' is not assignable to parameter ... ts(2345)*

I can't figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: On what line is the error and what is the _full_ error message?  The '...' parts seem highly relevant.  Is there any other relevant code not included? Are you importing or defining what `Book` is in the Child?

Comment: [working Vue Playground](https://shorturl.at/koGQT) with same `Book` interface included in both parent and child.

Comment: Oh sorry @yoduh ! The issue is in the parent component about the child component integrated in the template.
The CustomSelect is highlighted and the error is about the input. I simplified a lot my usecase but the complete msg is like:
Argument of type '{ bookOptions: ...' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ style?: unknown; readonly bookOptions?: Book[] | undefined; ... 9 more ...; class?: unknown; } & Record<...>'.

Comment: I just bypassed my error by replacing ```let bookList= ref<Book[]>([])``` by ```let bookList= ref<Book[]>()``` and instancing later the bookList value... really don't understand what I missed...